# Error message: Array ( ) Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had a query which ran perfectly smooth, updating the database with a new image title, that the user gave. Which can be seen below:

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblImage`";
    $result = $conn -> query($query);
    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
    {
?>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <a href="<?php echo $row['fldFilePath']; ?>" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="<?php echo $row['fldName']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['fldFilePath']; ?>" class="ImgRound"></a>

    <label>Image Name: <?php echo $row['fldName']; ?></label>

    <input name ="img-title" type ="text" placeholder="Enter New Image Title...">
    <button type="submit" value ="<?php echo $row['fldName'] ?>" name="update_title" class="ImgRound">Update Title</button>


    <button type="submit" value ="<?php echo $row['fldName'] ?>" name="delete" class="ImgRound">Delete</button>
    </form>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['update_title']))
        {
        $imgTitle = $_POST['img-title'];

        $stmt= "UPDATE `tblImage` SET `fldName` = '$imgTitle' WHERE `fldName` = '$_POST[update_title]' ";   


        $result = $conn -> query($stmt);    
        if($conn -> query($stmt))
            {
                header("Refresh:0");

            }   
        }

    }
?>
```

However, when I went back into the code to bind params for `$stmt`, I've made a mistake somewhere in the code, the error message is telling me:
 `Array ( ) 
Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`.

The update query that I tried which gave this message was:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tblImage` SET `fldName` = ? WHERE `fldName` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $imgTitle, $_POST['update-title']);
$stmt->execute();


if($conn -> query($stmt))
    {
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
```

I've looked on here under this error message and I'm struggling to still make sense of what I've done.

Comment: if you call `$stmt->execute()` you do not then call `$conn->query($stmt)` ~ at that point $stmt is an object

Comment: Hi @RamRaider I see!! Let me try that now, do you know what I should of placed in that if statement to get the header refresh

Comment: `$result = $conn -> query($stmt);    
 if($conn -> query($stmt))` that runs the query twice, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to pass your `$stmt` variable to `query()`. To check the success of the `UPDATE`, simply check the result of `execute()` instead:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tblImage` SET `fldName` = ? WHERE `fldName` = ?") or die($conn->error);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $imgTitle, $_POST['update_title']) or die($stmt->error);
if ($stmt->execute())
    {
        header("Refresh:0");
    }   
else {
    die($stmt->error);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nick thank you for explaining that, the error message has now gone however the image title is no longer updating. It's frustrating as I want to ensure the code is safe from SQL injection but it seems that $stmt. in the top code snippet, is the only one I can get to work.

Comment: @qwpozxmn strange the query looks right. You should check that `$stmt` is not `=== false` (in case the prepare failed) and also that `bind_param` worked. See my edit

Comment: @qwpozxmn you also have a typo in the `bind_param`, you have `$_POST['update-title']` where you should have `$_POST['update_title']`

Comment: Nick and RamRaider thank you SO much for your help with this one. So I should not have had `if($conn -> query($stmt))` also how embarrassing about the typo. BOTH answers are correct Im not sure which one to tick THANK you both!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Assign a variable to the `prepare` method so that you can test to see that the statement object has been created successfully and then assign a variable to the return value of `execute` to test that it too was successful.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare( "UPDATE `tblImage` SET `fldName` = ? WHERE `fldName` = ?" );
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $imgTitle, $_POST['update_title']);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if( $result )exit( header("Refresh:0") );
}
```

-- updated

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblImage`";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    while( $row = $result -> fetch_assoc() ) {

?>

    <form method="post">
        <a href="<?php echo $row['fldFilePath']; ?>" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="<?php echo $row['fldName']; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $row['fldFilePath']; ?>" class="ImgRound" alt='' />
        </a>
        <label>Image Name: <?php echo $row['fldName']; ?></label>
        <input name="img-title" type="text" placeholder="Enter New Image Title..." />
        <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['fldName'] ?>" name="update_title" class="ImgRound">Update Title</button>
        <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['fldName'] ?>" name="delete" class="ImgRound">Delete</button>
    </form>


<?php

    } #close loop here ???

?>


<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['update_title'], $_POST['img-title'] ) ) {

        $imgTitle = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'img-title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $updateTitle = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'update_title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        if( $imgTitle & $updateTitle ){

            $stmt = $conn->prepare( 'UPDATE `tblImage` SET `fldName` = ? WHERE `fldName` = ?' );

            if( $stmt ){
                $stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $imgTitle, $updateTitle );
                $result = $stmt->execute();
                if( $result )exit( header("Refresh:0") );
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi  @RamRaider thank you for that, I've also tried your code suggestion above and again, it doesn't seem to be making any changes to the table anymore, i.e. the image title. I'm sure it shouldn't matter as to whether I bind my params or not, hmmm!

Comment: I think, correct me if I'm wrong, that the issue might be that your form element is named `update_title` yet your look for `$_POST['update-title']` in the update query...

Comment: @RamRaider seems we were both making the comment about the typo at the same time...

Comment: Nick and RamRaider thank you SO much for your help with this one. So I should not have had if($conn -> query($stmt)) also how embarrassing about the typo. BOTH answers are correct Im not sure which one to tick THANK you both!!!!

Comment: @RamRaider since you should get something for all this effort... +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $imgTitle, $_POST['update-title']);
```

You are giving 3 parameters here.

Shouldn't it be like this ..

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tblImage` SET `fldName` = ? WHERE `fldName` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param($_POST['update-title'], $imgTitle);
```

Assumed,
 `$_POST['update-title']` - the updated value.
 `$imgTitle` - to be updated value

Comment: Hi @KushalArya I was under the impression that you had to give the type of information it would expect i.e. 'i' for interger, 's' for string, let me try that though anyway :)

Comment: @qwpozxmn the way you are using `bind_param` is correct, this answer is wrong. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php